# Angular-Meteor: What is the proper way to cancel client side changes?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I have seen the save method in several tutorials that make the collection.update call to save the changes made on the client but what is the proper way of discarding the changes?

Answer (score 0):

`Collection.remove` is for removing document from db while I won't call this "discarding changes". If you want to discard changes made with update you need to store previous version of variable and update collection again with that. Mongo itself doesn't have "version control"so you have to do it manually.